# R New columns based on presence or absence of outcomes in other columns

Tags: r

I have my fingers crossed that one (or more) of you fine people will be able to help...

For example, say I have the following df in R.

```
ID <- as.factor (c(1:6))
Pop <- as.factor(c(1,0,1,0,0,0))
Jazz <- as.factor(c(1,0,0,1,1,0))
Classical <- as.factor(c(0,0,1,0,0,0))
Rap <- as.factor(c(1,1,1,0,1,0))
   df <- data.frame(ID, Pop, Jazz, Classical, Rap)
```

I would basically like to create the following...

```
ID <- as.factor (c(1:6))
Pop <- as.factor(c(1,0,1,0,0,0))
Jazz <- as.factor(c(1,0,0,1,1,0))
Classical <- as.factor(c(0,0,1,0,0,0))
Rap <- as.factor(c(1,1,1,0,1,0))
Music_1 <- c("Pop","Rap","Pop","Jazz","Jazz",NA)
Music_2 <- c("Jazz",NA,"Classical",NA,"Rap",NA)
Music_3 <- c("Rap",NA,"Rap",NA,NA,NA)
    df2 <- data.frame(ID, Pop, Jazz, Classical, Rap, Music_1, Music_2, Music_3)
```

where each ID is reviewed for their music preference and then these choices (using the headings from the appropriate columns) are printed in new columns with continuous numbered headings (e.g. Music_1, Music_2, Music_3...).

I have tried a few ways of doing this but have had limited success. The real dataframe is larger with over 70 columns so I've been attempting to use `for` loops but happy to have any alternative suggestions.

Please let me know if this is unclear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do a `gather` to 'long' format, `filter` out the rows where the 'val' is 0, grouped by 'ID', create a sequence column ('ind'), `spread` it to 'wide' format and then join with the original data by 'ID' (even without specifying it, by default it picks up the common column for joining)

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  gather(key, val, -ID) %>% 
  filter(val == 1) %>% 
  select(-val) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(ind = paste0("Music", row_number())) %>% 
  spread(ind, key) %>% 
  right_join(df) %>%
  select(names(df), everything())
# A tibble: 6 x 8
# Groups:   ID [6]
#  ID    Pop   Jazz  Classical Rap   Music1 Music2    Music3
#  <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>     <fct> <chr>  <chr>     <chr> 
#1 1     1     1     0         1     Pop    Jazz      Rap   
#2 2     0     0     0         1     Rap    <NA>      <NA>  
#3 3     1     0     1         1     Pop    Classical Rap   
#4 4     0     1     0         0     Jazz   <NA>      <NA>  
#5 5     0     1     0         1     Jazz   Rap       <NA>  
#6 6     0     0     0         0     <NA>   <NA>      <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun for the nice solution.

Comment: Hi sps_, can you click the check mark under @akrun's response and accept it? This increases a Stack Overflow user's rating.